# Solve For x where $0\leq x \leq 360$

Tags: trigonometry

solve for $x$ where $0 \leq x \leq 360$:
$$2\sin x=\tan x$$
I tried this and I ended up with
$$\cos x=2$$
Steps:
$\sin x = \tan x/2$

$\sin x =(\sin x/\cos x)/2$

$\sin x = \cos x/2\sin x$

$2=\cos x$

to find $x$ I did $\cos^{-1}$, but $\cos^{-1}2$ is a math error

Comment: You have a mistake!

Comment: Your manipulation of the fraction is wrong.  Just divide the initial expression by $\sin x$ (noting that you have to check $\sin x = 0 $ separately).  You get $2 = \frac 1{\cos x}$.

Comment: $\cos x =\frac 12$ from $2\sin x=\tan x$

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$2\sin x=\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\iff 2\sin x\cos x=\sin x\iff \sin x=0, \cos x=\frac 12.$$

Your problem is in the step

$$\frac{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}}{2}.$$ It is $$\frac{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}}{2}=\frac{\sin x}{2\cos x}.$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: rewrite your equation in the form
$$\sin(x)\left(\frac{2\cos(x)-1}{\cos(x)}\right)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the equation you wanted to solve as $2\sin x = \tan x$, the solution would go something like this:-

$$2\sin x = \dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}$$
$$\therefore 2\sin x\cos x = \sin x$$
$$\therefore \sin 2x - \sin x = 0$$
$$\therefore 2\cos \left( \dfrac{3x}{2} \right)\sin \left( \dfrac{x}{2} \right) = 0$$
which means $\dfrac{3x}{2} = \dfrac{\pi}{2} or \dfrac{3\pi}{2}$ OR $\dfrac{x}{2} = \pi or 2\pi$.

Solving for x, we get $x =  0, \dfrac{\pi}{3}, \pi$ are your solutions.

Comment: You forgot $2\pi=360$ solution.

Comment: $2\pi = 360 = 0$. All three values are the same!

Answer (score 0):

$$2\sin (x)=\frac {\sin (x)}{\cos (x)} $$

$$\implies \sin (2x)=\sin (x) $$
$$\implies $$
$$2x=x+2k\pi $$
or
$$2x=\pi-x+2k\pi $$

thus
$$x=2k\pi $$
or
$$x=\frac {2k+1}{3}\pi $$

for $k=0,1$, we find
$$x\in \{0,\frac {\pi}{3},\pi,2\pi\}=\{0,60,180, 360\}$$